# Stretching <a> tags across a sidebar while vertically aligning its contents to the center

Tags: html, css

I want to put a bunch of clickable links in a sidebar with a hover effect that covers the entire width of the sidebar. Some of these links also include an image that needs to be aligned so that it's vertically centered in relation to the text. Here's what I currently have:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the hover effect and the `<a>` tag don't cover the entire width of the sidebar yet. That's bad because of [big link targets are easier to click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law). I've tried tinkering with horizontally stretched CSS-based table cells, but then the text parts didn't stay aligned properly.

What's the proper way to do it? ~I could post my current HTML if it's helpful, but I was planning to rewrite my markup based on this answer's solution anyway.~

---

**Edit**: here's the relevant HTML snippet.

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <header>Recently Added</header>
    <ul id="recents">
        <li><a href="/play/q2music/"><img src="http://media.radiantstreamer.net/stations/q2music.png" alt="Artwork"> <span>Q2 Music</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/play/moclassic/"><img src="http://media.radiantstreamer.net/stations/rtmoclassic.png" alt="Artwork"> <span>Mostly Classical</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/play/pitrios/"><img src="http://media.radiantstreamer.net/stations/rtpitrios.png" alt="Artwork"> <span>Piano Trios</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `display: block;` on the relevant links should make them full width. Or if it doesn't, `display: block; width: 100%;`.  `width: 100%` on its own doesn't seem to be much use on inline elements.

…And some positioning to fix the alignment, e.g.

```
ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
ul li a span {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
```

Comment: Yup, my answer was just a quick thought, just tested it and it didn't work

Comment: I've tried that before, but that breaks the vertical alignment of the images: http://i.imgur.com/ihs769H.png

Comment: @Pieter …oops. Yeah, it would do that. Some positioning in the CSS should fix it. Added an example to my original answer.

Comment: That will align the *top* of the `<span>` container to the vertical center while I should be aligning the *middle* of the `<span>` container to the vertical center: http://i.imgur.com/tsKxdS6.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `position: absolute; width: 100%` (or something like that) on your links? That should make it the parent's full width.

Answer (score 0):

## How I solved it

First I made my `<a>` tags render as a one-row CSS table by setting them to `display: table` and its children to `display: table-cell`. You'll need to add `width: 100%` to the table tag to make it stretch horizontally. But then the text didn't align properly:

[image: Screenshot]

Adding a `width: 100%` to `<span>` containing the text does the trick:

[image: Screenshot]

Uh oh... the 5 pixels of left padding on my links are causing spillover on the right. The fix was fairly easy: wrap the link tags in another `<span>` tag and adjust the CSS `display` rules so that the new `<span>` renders as a table. Bam!

[image: Screenshot]

## Summary

I've prepared a [minimally working HTML5-compliant example](http://jsfiddle.net/pieterdd/4zwce8hc/2/) for the benefit of future readers.